# Wait for Web Page to fully load before taking its Screenshot using Google Sheets and Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code that enables me to insert a list of URLs inside Google Sheets and take their screenshots using Apps Script and a Screenshot API (screenshotlayer API).

However one of the websites has a built-in loading screen and I keep getting the screenshot of the loading screen instead of the fully loaded page.

How could I make Apps Script wait X amount of seconds before taking the screenshot ?

Here's the code:

```
function onOpen() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menu = [ 
    {name: "Start capturing", functionName: "startTriggers"},
    {name: "Stop capturing", functionName: "stopTriggers"},
    {name: "Verify now", functionName: "verifyCapturing"}
    ];   
    sheet.addMenu("Capture Webpage", menu);
    sheet.toast("You can also start the app from menu bar.", "Message", 7);    
}

function startTriggers(){
    var sheet = getSheet();
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    if(triggers.length>0){
        Browser.msgBox("Message", "Application is already started !", Browser.Buttons.OK);
        return false;
    }
    Logger.log(sheet.getRange("D9").getValue());
    switch(sheet.getRange("D9").getValue()){
      case "Once in a day": 
        ScriptApp.newTrigger("captureWebPage").timeBased().everyDays(1).create();
        break;
      case "Once in a week": 
        ScriptApp.newTrigger("captureWebPage").timeBased().everyDays(7).create();
        break;
      case "Once in a month": 
        ScriptApp.newTrigger("captureWebPage").timeBased().everyDays(30).create();
        break;
    }
    sheet.getRange("D6").setBackground("#48C42F").setFontColor("#fff");
    Browser.msgBox("Message", "Application has been started. The screenshots will be stored in 'Webpage captures' folder in your Google Drive", Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
      
function stopTriggers(){
    var sheet = getSheet();
    sheet.getRange("D6").setBackground("#ffffff").setFontColor("#000000");
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
    }
    Browser.msgBox("Message", "Application has been stopped.", Browser.Buttons.OK);
}
      
      
function captureWebPage() {
  var sheet = getSheet();
  createFolderIfNotExist();
  var url = "http://api.screenshotlayer.com/api/capture?access_key="+sheet.getRange("D3").getValue()+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(sheet.getRange("D6").getValue())+"&fullpage=1";
   var url2 = "http://api.screenshotlayer.com/api/capture?access_key="+sheet.getRange("D3").getValue()+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(sheet.getRange("C24").getValue())+"&fullpage=1"; 
   var url3 = "http://api.screenshotlayer.com/api/capture?access_key="+sheet.getRange("D3").getValue()+"&url="+encodeURIComponent(sheet.getRange("C25").getValue())+"&fullpage=1";
                           
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2);
  var fileBlob2 = response2.getBlob();
  var response3 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url3);
  var fileBlob3 = response3.getBlob();
                    
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_NAME).next();
  var result = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  var time = new Date().toLocaleString();
  result.setName(time+" ("+sheet.getRange("D6").getValue()+").png");
  sheet.getRange("A"+getLastRow()).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange("D12").setValue(sheet.getRange("D12").getValue()+1);

  var result = folder.createFile(fileBlob2);
  var time = new Date().toLocaleString();
  result.setName(time+" ("+sheet.getRange("D24").getValue()+").png");
  sheet.getRange("A"+getLastRow()).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange("D12").setValue(sheet.getRange("D12").getValue()+1);

  var result = folder.createFile(fileBlob3);
  var time = new Date().toLocaleString();
  result.setName(time+" ("+sheet.getRange("D25").getValue()+").png");
  sheet.getRange("A"+getLastRow()).setValue(time);
  sheet.getRange("D12").setValue(sheet.getRange("D12").getValue()+1);         
  
}

function verifyCapturing(){
  captureWebPage();
  Browser.msgBox("Message","Web page has been captured. Visit your Google Drive to view the captured image.",Browser.Buttons.OK);
}

function getLastRow(){
  var sheet = getSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
  if(sheet.getLastRow()<=20){
    var i = 1;
    while(sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue()!=""){
      i++;
    }
    lastRow = i;
  }
  return lastRow;
}

function getSheet(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings");
}

function createFolderIfNotExist(){
  var sheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolders();
  var exist = false;  
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    if (folders.next().getName() == GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_NAME) {
      exist = true;
      break; 
    }
  }  
  if (!exist) {
    DriveApp.createFolder(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_NAME)
  }
}
```

And here's the file template:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFVNxkDPlaX8ylIM4Uj5ceXgicLZ-EJ84QeOtU-fI2w/edit#gid=0

Comment: Have you tried using a `Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)` inside the script? It should be place before the screenshot is taken. The maximum allowed value is 300000 (or 5 minutes). You can read more information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)

Comment: @GiselleValladares thank you for your response. I have tried putting Utilities.sleep(20000) after "UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)" and right before getBlob. Unfortunately it didn't work.